# How to get topojson's geometry by name (properties' value)?

Tags: javascript, topojson

I am a TopoJson newbie and I have some data that looks like this....

```
{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"name":"Arkansas"},"arcs":[[0,1,2,3,4,5]]}
```

I am trying to say just output Arkansas so I cam up with the following (I am using underscore.js)...

```
var collection = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.subunits).features;
  var final = [];
  _.forEach(collection, function(item){
    if(item.properties.name == "Arkansas"){
      final.push(item);
    }
  });
  svg.selectAll(".subunit")
     .data(final)
     .enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
     .attr("d", path);
```

This works great but isn't there an easier way? Is there something like us.objects.subunits["Arkansas"] I can do?

Answer (score 1):

(From my mobile and memory, try out the following)

Usually, the way to go is something like :

```
var final = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.subunits).features;
  svg.selectAll(".subunit")
      .data(final)
    .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
      .attr("d", function(d){ if(d.properties.name == "Arkansas"){ return d }  });
```

The filtering is directly within the `.attr('d', function(d){…})`. If not working, try `.attr('d', function(d, path){…})` and return the path.